# AMPScript - No column of the specified name was found but the field is present

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

I need to have different HTML rendered based on the value of a couple of fields in my DE. Except when I try to preview the email I get this error.

> Invalid column name (parameter 2) passed to Field function. No column of the specified name was found. Invalid Field Name: Image1Link Function: field(@row,"Image1Link")

However, the field is present in the DE as you can see here. [image: Data Extension fields]

Here is the AMPScript I'm using.

```
%%[ 
SET @rows = LookupOrderedRows("TestDE",1,"Timestamp DESC","EmailAddress", emailaddr) 
SET @row = row(@rows,1) 
SET @Image1Link= field(@row,"Image1Link") 
SET @Image2Link= field(@row,"Image2Link") 
]%%

%%[ IF (NOT Empty(@Image1Link) AND NOT Empty(@Image2Link)) THEN ]%% 
<!-- HTML HERE -->
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```

Comment: Are you sure, the DE field definition does not contain a whitespace after the name Image1Link? So it basically is "Image1Link "?

Comment: @LukasLunow I had the same doubt and I checked and also renamed the field to be sure, no whitespaces.

Comment: Can you please update your screenshot to include the name of the TestDE Data Extension?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs OMG you made me check the name of the Data Extension, the whitespace was there. I feel so dumb now. Thank you